# Multiple audio tracks in the same activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating an audio playback application. I've currently just got two tracks added but eventually I need to add many more... I've currently created two different mediaplayers to run both the tracks, however as the number of tracks will increase using this procedure will lead to problems and lack of performance!

Is there some way I can code this better and more generically?

Here's the java code

```
public class ChantsFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView text1, text2
    ImageButton play1, play2, pause1, pause2, repeatoff1, repeatoff2, repeaton1, repeaton2, stop1, stop2;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1, mediaPlayer2;
    Toast on, off;

    public ChantsFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chants, container, false);


        play1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play1);
        play2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.play2);
        pause1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pause1);
        pause2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pause2);
        repeatoff1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.repeatoff1);
        repeatoff2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.repeatoff2);
        repeaton1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.repeaton1);
        repeaton2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.repeaton2);
        stop1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.stop1);
        stop2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.stop2);

        mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.audio1);
        mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.audio2);

        on = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The chant will repeat itself", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        off = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The chant will no longer repeat itself", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        //Track 1

        text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer1 != null && mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {
                    text1.setClickable(false);
                }

                if (mediaPlayer2 != null && mediaPlayer2.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer2.stop();
                    mediaPlayer2.release();
                    mediaPlayer2 = null;
                    play2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    repeatoff2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    repeaton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    stop2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (mediaPlayer1 == null) {
                    mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.audio1);
                } else {
                    text1.setClickable(true);
                    mediaPlayer1.start();
                    play1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    stop1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                mediaPlayer1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        play1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pause1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        repeaton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        stop1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        play1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaPlayer1.start();
            }
        });

        pause1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mediaPlayer1.pause();
            }
        });

        repeatoff1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
                repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeaton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                on.show();
                off.cancel();
            }
        });

        repeaton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer1.setLooping(false);
                repeaton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                off.show();
                on.cancel();
            }
        });

        stop1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer1.stop();
                mediaPlayer1 = null;
                text1.setClickable(true);
                play1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeaton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stop1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        //Track 2

        text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer2 != null && mediaPlayer2.isPlaying()) {
                    text2.setClickable(false);
                }

                if (mediaPlayer1 != null && mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer1.stop();
                    mediaPlayer1.release();
                    mediaPlayer1 = null;
                    play1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    repeaton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    stop1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (mediaPlayer2 == null) {
                    mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.audio2);
                } else {
                    text2.setClickable(true);
                    mediaPlayer2.start();
                    play2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pause2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    repeatoff2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    stop2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                mediaPlayer2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        play2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pause2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        repeatoff2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        repeaton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        stop2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        play2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaPlayer2.start();
            }
        });

        pause2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mediaPlayer2.pause();
            }
        });

        repeatoff2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer2.setLooping(true);
                repeatoff2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeaton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                on.show();
                off.cancel();
            }
        });

        repeaton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer2.setLooping(false);
                repeaton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeatoff2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                off.show();
                on.cancel();
            }
        });

        stop2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer2.stop();
                mediaPlayer2 = null;
                text2.setClickable(true);
                play2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeatoff2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                repeaton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stop2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Edit

I've currently zeroed down on adding around 10 tracks to the application. I want playback to stop on the current track (if playing) the moment another track is selected and using media player to do the same would mean checking separately if 9 media players are playing! (Unless of course there's another way to do this which I've completely missed)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for playing multiple audio files at once, `SoundPool` seems to be your best choice mainly because its much more lightweight and you can control the number of streams. You can create a new `SoundPool` instance as:

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100); // 10 = maxStreams, 100 = quality
```

You can then start loading different sounds into it as:

```
int soundId1 = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.audio1, 1);
int soundId2 = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.audio2, 1);
...
```

You can control playback as:

```
int idBeingPlayed = soundPool.play (soundID, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1); // volume params, returns the streamId
```

Other controls:

```
soundPool.pause(streamID);
soundPool.resume(streamID);
```

For more info, visit the [offfical docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried using Sound Pool but the issue I'm facing is it does not let me check whether a sound is currently playing. If you go through my code above, I want a particular track to stop playing when I select another one, something which I was able to achieve through media player. I'll be adding about 10 tracks currently, and I want playback to stop on the current track (if playing) when I select another track! And using the media player to do that will mean extremely long lines of code and if I need to add even one new track to the code it'll be a mess!

Comment: Well in the `play`call in my code above, I'm also saving the `idBeingPlayed` variable. Calling `soundPool.pause(idBeingPlayed);` before calling play on another ID doesn't stop the current playing one?

Comment: If I call pause or stop without it actually being played it throws a NullPointer exception and the app crashes

Comment: So, you make sure that these variables are initialized properly before accessing them. Its just that in your use case independently re-initialising the ten audio tracks may be a bit heavy with `MediaPlayer`

Comment: Exactly the media player is just not feasible. Its also to do with the layout I'm using, I'm not using a play button the first time to get the track to play. The track plays when the text / name of the track is clicked, thus the need to check if another chant is currently playing and stop it, otherwise it leads to two tracks being played at the same time among other problems!

Comment: @Devansh yeah...the logic to handle multiple track playback will need to be exhaustively handled.